# How to check iterator number based on int array?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm going through and trying to replace known data based on its position in the array.

I have split the CSV file into the "split" array. The positions within split that need to be replaced are in the "error" array.

However, I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception for the if(error[i] == i). I know that this is getting an error due to the split array being a different length than the error array.

Is there anyway around this?

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
```

---

```
            String[] split = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) 
            {

                int[] error = {0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,15,21,34,37,57,61,65,68,69,71,75,79,82,83,85,89,93,96,97,99,103,107,110,111,113,117,121,124,125,127,128,129,130,132,182,210,212,213,214,215,216,222,226,239};
                String fix = "ignore_";

                if(error[i] == i){
                split[i] = fix + i;

            }

            sb.append(split[i]);

            if(i != split.length - 1)
            {
                sb.append(" ");
            }

        }

        String newline = sb.toString();
        printWriter.println(newline);
    }

} catch (Throwable t) 
{
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sample CSV:

```
"Start Date","End Date","Export App Name","Username","User Last Name",
"User First Name","Response ID","Response Date/Time","Device Date/Time",
"Submission Form Name","Submission Form Version"
```

This CSV text is split into an array based on the format. "Start Date" is first element of the split array, "End Date" is second.

I want to for example (based of first two numbers is error array) replace "Start Date" and "End Date" with whatever I define the String fix to be.

So after running through the loop, I'd want my output to be:

```
"ignore_1","ignore_2","Export App Name","Username","User Last Name",
"User First Name","Response ID","Response Date/Time","Device Date/Time",
"Submission Form Name","Submission Form Version"
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you include a sample of the input, along with a sample of the expected output. An array may not be the best data structure for holding the positions of interest. You may want to look into using a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and the `contains` method.

Comment: I've added some additional details along with sample input/output.

Comment: @Chris what is meaning by this split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

Comment: That is saying to split the string based on commas, but to ignore commas within double quotes.

Comment: Please check my answer if it resolve your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34007073/3361850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB:** You can use the declaration of `error` array before `while` loop, it will be better.

**Solution:**

- You must add  also an other `for` loop to iterate `error` array

inside `for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {`  like that:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < error.length; j++){

                    if(error[j] == i){
                       split[i] = fix;
                    }
        }
```

**Explanation:**

- For each index(position) `i` of `split` array will check if this index(position) correspond of an element in `error` array.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility using a HashSet for storing the columns of interest. Rather than iterating over an array looking for a value, the HashSet provides a constant time lookup of a value.

```
HashSet<Integer> replace = new HashSet<Integer>(
    Arrays.asList(0,1)
);

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] split = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (replace.contains(i)) {
            // Do something with the column value.
        }
        else {
            // Leave as is. 
        }
    }
}
```